# What are tainted objects, and when should we untaint them?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, taint, taint-checking

When do Ruby objects need to be made tainted and when should we untaint them? How does the concept of tainted object make a Ruby script run in safe mode? Can anyone elaborate on this to make the concept clear with some code snippets?

Comment: Related answer, but not a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14259324/1301972

Comment: Can a bit focus on to the question `How does the concept of tainted object make a Ruby script run in safe mode?`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### What is Tainted?

User input is tainted, by definition. For example:

```
string = gets
string.tainted?
# => true
```

You can also manually taint an object.

```
string = 'Not yet tainted.'
string.tainted?
# => false

(string = 'Explicitly taint me!').taint
string.tainted?
# => true
```

#### Why Untaint an Object?

Generally, you would untaint an object only after you validate and/or sanitize it. Untainting an object marks it as "safe" for certain operations that you wouldn't want to run on untrusted strings or other objects, or when your safe level requires an untainted object to perform the desired operation.

#### Untainting an Object

The easiest way to untaint an object is to call the [Object#untaint](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-untaint) method on it. For example, if your *string* variable holds a tainted object, then:

```
(string = "Let's taint this string!").taint
string.untaint.tainted?
# => false
```

#### More About Tainted Objects

You can find out more about tainted objects from the [Locking Ruby in the Safe](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/taint.html) chapter of *Programming Ruby*.

Comment: Perfect explanation! `+1` to you! but `How does the concept of tainted object make a Ruby script run in safe mode?` any suggestions on this question?

Comment: @PythonLikeYOU I updated the answer to reflect when you might want to untaint an object. By itself, (un)tainting doesn't do anything except change a flag on your object. It really only matters when you're concerned about the safety of your inputs (e.g. SQL injection or #eval methods), or when `$SAFE >= 1`.

Comment: has my above asked question(in comment) also answered? I am just wandering in your post!

Comment: What does `"safe" for certain operations` mean? which operations are being referred to here?